# Owncloud has no installation cadidate, how do I fix?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04, owncloud

I am trying to install Owncloud server on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and have been following [these instructions from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-owncloud-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it has gone flawlessly up until the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

So I tried running

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud-files
```

Which something installed, but it didn't do the installer as expected per the Digital Ocean instructions

To be clear, I have done all of the steps leading up to the install of owncloud.

```
$ sudo curl https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for user: 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4502  100  4502    0     0   3847      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3847
OK

$ echo 'deb https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
deb https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /

$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:7 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.3 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [644 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [57.6 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.6 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [80.0 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [611 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [305 kB]
Ign:19 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [213 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [540 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [516 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [173 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [240 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,584 B]
Hit:28 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Fetched 3,809 kB in 1s (1,932 kB/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package owncloud is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  owncloud-files

E: Package 'owncloud' has no installation candidate
```

That is everything that happens when I follow the steps, it still says there is no 'owncloud' installation candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that ownCloud recently dropped the `owncloud` meta-package (that can be harmful in environments with multiple applications hosted simultaneously). The difference with the `owncloud-files` package is [described in the docs](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/linux_installation.html):

> owncloud-files (recommended): This package installs only ownCloud. It does not install Apache, a database, or any PHP dependencies.
>
> owncloud: This package installs ownCloud, complete with all dependencies.

So, basically, you downloaded and installed ownCloud on your system (you'll see it living under your `/var/www/owncloud` dir.) - but now it's missing its dependencies. You'll need to install them manually; you can see a list in: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#install-the-required-packages:

```
sudo apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 \
    php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl \
    php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick \
    php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

After the installation, you'll be prompted with the apache wizard you were missing from the DigitalOcean tutorial. From there you'll be able to customize the server installation. In case you need more info on how to complete the process, see: [configuring the apache server](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#configure-apache-web-server) and [completing the installation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#run-the-installation-wizard)